# How do I access an element from an integer like a list?

Tags: python, integer

I try to run the code:

```
for c in range(10, 21):
    print(c)
    print([c[1]])
```

And I get the error:
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
Why? How can I pick a specific element from an integer?

Comment: Are you trying to get the 1st digit from an integer? Eg if `c = 10`, you want `c[1] = 0`?

Comment: `int` objects are not containers, they do not have any elements. Are you trying to get a specific digit from their digital representation? The easiest way would be to convert it to a string, so something like `int(str(c)[1])`

Comment: Also, that *isn't* the error you get, you get "Int item is not subscriptable".

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to get the 1st digit from an integer

Comment: Integers don't have digits. They don't have a base, either. Those are properties of *textual representations of* integers.

Answer (score -1):

you are iterating in an iterable, you need to declare before the list to access to the element something like this:

```
a = range(10,21)
for i in a:
    print(i)
    print(a[1])
```

In your code every iteration the value of c are:
10
11
12
13
...
This is the reason of you error

Comment: This misunderstands the question.